# Represent the definition of elementary substructure in FOL

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I know the definition of elementary substructure $\mathcal{M} \prec \mathcal{N}$, when $M$ and $N$ are two structure of a language $\mathcal{L}$. My doubt is how to represent the relation $\mathcal{M} \prec \mathcal{N}$ using a first order formula(in the language of the set theory outside the model theory we are discussing currently)? To describe this relation, we need to traverse all strings which represents a *w.f.f.* in $\mathcal{L}$(*w.f.f* of $\mathcal{L}$ are differ from the formulas in the "outer" set theory). For a specific *w.f.f* $\varphi$, how can we apply this formula to $\mathcal{M}$ or $\mathcal{N}$ and talk about the satisfiability? Here $\varphi$ is just a string, we couldn't interpret quantifiers and variables in $\varphi$ in the same way as what we have done in the outer language(where our set theory really lived in).

In short, how can we calculate(define) the semantic(truth value) of a *w.f.f.* $\varphi$ in the discourse $\mathcal{M}$ using one formula in the language of the "outer" set theory.

Comment: You can't represent the relation $\mathcal{M} \prec \mathcal{N}$ using a first-order formula. This is meta-knowledge. By the way in which language would such a formula be written?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I'm sure that $\mathcal{M} \prec \mathcal{N}$ could be write down in a first-order formula. I just want to understand the details...

Comment: Your two questions are unrelated, so they should be asked as separate questions.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net is quite right that the elementary substructure relation between $L$-structures cannot be defined in the language $L$ (and it's not even clear what it would mean to express it as an $L$-formula). But I think the intention of your question was to express this relation as a first-order formula in the meta-language. So you should specify your meta-language and theory: is it ZFC in the language of set theory?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Oh.., I will separate them later. I think your understanding is almost what I want to ask. According to my personal understanding, the model theory was constructed inside the set theory, in which the first-order formulas I mentioned take place. Same as the general acceptance, I assume the axiom of this "outer" set theory is $ZFC$. I think my consideration is the same as you mentioned, but delete every "meta-" prefix(Although I didn't know which is the correct way to put up this question).

Comment: Is there a textbook you're working from?  Any model theory text should include the recursive definition of satisfaction in a model.  Then you just implement that recursive definition in your metatheory.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, I'm reading David Marker's textbook. He used a recursive definition to define satisfaction indeed. But I don't understand how to translate it to a formula. Maybe I need some kind of $\beta-$function lemma here?

Comment: Do you know how to generally implement recursion in ZFC?  There's nothing special at all about model theory here; implementing the recursive definition of satisfaction is no different from implementing any other recursive definition that is commonly used in mathematics.  (For instance, it is analogous to defining the operation in a group that takes any finite sequence of group elements to their product.)

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh, I see. Almost got it. But would quantifiers in formulas bring difficulties to the recursive definition here? Since we need to interpret them as something traverse the whole model.

Comment: No, you just use a metalanguage quantifier in that step of the recursive definition.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comments, I'm going to address the question: "How do we talk about elementary substructurehood inside $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (which is a first-order theory)?"

---

This question reduces to the following more natural one:

> How can we define, given a structure $\mathcal{M}$, the set $\mathcal{ED}(\mathcal{M})$ of all true sentences in the language of $\mathcal{M}$ + parameters from $\mathcal{M}$?

(Here "$\mathcal{ED}$" stands for "elementary diagram.")

The rough idea is as follows. First, we define the set of all "$\mathcal{M}$-formulas" *(= formulas in the language of $\mathcal{M}$ + constants corresponding to elements of $\mathcal{M}$)* and "$\mathcal{M}$-sentences" *(= $\mathcal{M}$-formulas without free variables - this is what we actually care about)*. This is no harder than defining formulas and sentences as usual, the only subtlety being the need to pick at the outset a family of unused constant symbols to name the elements of $\mathcal{M}$.

To recap, we now have a formula which defines an assignment to each structure $\mathcal{M}$ in a language $\Sigma$ a set $Sent(\mathcal{M})$ of sentences in a larger language $\Sigma_\mathcal{M}$. We now make a further definition:

> A **satisfaction function for $\mathcal{M}$** is a function $f:Sent(\mathcal{M})\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ satisfying the following rules:
>
> - If $\varphi\in Sent(\mathcal{M})$ is atomic, then $f(\varphi)=1\iff \mathcal{M}\models\varphi$.
>
>   - Yes, I just used "$\models$" - don't worry, I'll explain why that's okay below.
> - If $\varphi$ has the form $\neg\psi$ then $f(\varphi)=1-f(\psi)$.
> - If $\varphi$ has the form $\psi\wedge\theta$ then $f(\varphi)=\min\{f(\psi),f(\theta)\}$.
> - If $\varphi$ has the form $\forall x\psi(x)$ then $f(\varphi)=\min_{a\in\mathcal{M}}f(\psi[x/c_a])$, where $c_a$ is the new constant symbol corresonding to $a$.

We then prove in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (or indeed vastly less) that for every $\mathcal{M}$ there is exactly one satisfaction function for $\mathcal{M}$; this is a quick application of the **recursion theorem** (or a slightly less quick application if you're using a narrower version of the theorem).

The only weird point in the above is the use of $\models$ in the atomic clause. But the point is that we only every ask about the atomic senteces true in $\mathcal{M}$ here, so we just need an "atomic satisfaction predicate." And this is easy: it's basically already in $\mathcal{M}$ itself, in the form of $\mathcal{M}$'s **interpretation** of the various symbols in $\Sigma$.

We then define $\mathcal{ED}(\mathcal{M})$ as the set of $\Sigma_\mathcal{M}$-sentences which the unique satisfaction function for $\mathcal{M}$ maps to $1$. Elementary substructurehood is then definable as $$\mathcal{A}\preccurlyeq\mathcal{B}\quad\iff\quad \mathcal{ED}(\mathcal{A})\subseteq \mathcal{ED}(\mathcal{B}).$$

(There is actually a minor subtlety here around picking new constant symbols corresonding to elements of structures, the point being that our comparison of $\mathcal{ED}(\mathcal{A})$ and $\mathcal{ED}(\mathcal{B})$ presupposes that $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ use the same constant symbols for elements of $\mathcal{A}$. This can be addressed in a couple different ways: we can talk about the "translation" of $\Sigma_\mathcal{A}$ into $\Sigma_\mathcal{B}$, or we can whip up a uniform way of picking constant symbols.)

---

As a coda, here are a couple comments:

- Note that the definition of $\mathcal{ED}$ above is really just the standard definition of $\models$ as it appears in logic textbooks; as usual, the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ implementation is just a careful rephrasing of the standard presentation. In particular, this tells us how to talk about (say) quantifier elimination in the language of set theory: a theory $T$ in a language $\Sigma$ eliminates quantifiers iff for every $\Sigma$-formula $\varphi(x_1,...,x_n)$ there is some quantifier-free $\Sigma$-formula $\psi(x_1,...,x_n)$ such that for every $\Sigma$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ and every tuple of elements $a_1,...,a_n\in\mathcal{M}$ we have $$f(\varphi[x_1/c_{a_1},..., x_n/c_{a_n}])=f(\psi[x_1/c_{a_1},..., x_n/c_{a_n}])$$ where $f$ is the unique satisfaction function for $\mathcal{M}$. This line of thought addresses [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4091537/what-does-model-theoretic-proofs-really-prove) by showing how the various notions of model theory are expressible in set theory with no funny business, so proofs via model theory are totally genuine; my comment there meanwhile is aimed at addressing the general "sense of mystery" around model theory which I think enhances these concerns.
- This argument also serves as a "blueprint" for more complicated logics. We can, again in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, define what it means for one structure to be an elementary substructure of another with respect to (say) **second-order logic** in place of first-order logic; the key point is in the definition of the appropriate analogue of the elementary diagram $\mathcal{ED}(\mathcal{M})$, and this will just consist of **the standard description of the semantics of that logic**. So e.g. part of the definition for second-order logic is "If $\varphi$ has the form $\exists X\psi(X)$," then $f(\varphi)=\min_{A\subseteq\mathcal{M}}f(\psi[X/R_A])$" where now $R_A$ is a fresh relation symbol naming $A$ - since our quantifiers are ranging over more things, we need to use more "expanded" language than just fresh *constant* symbols naming *elements* of the structure. The general study of logics beyond first-order logic is called **abstract model theory**, and - while quite technical - the standard text on the subject is the collection [*Model-theoretic logics*](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Model-Theoretic-Logics/toc/pl/1235417263).